# Linear transformation of overdetermined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, systems-of-equations, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume that we have the following over-determined linear system
\begin{cases}
z_{1}=c + \phi z_0\\
z_{2}=c + \phi z_{1}\\
\dots\\
z_{n} = c + \phi z_{n-1}
\end{cases}
with $n>2$ and all $z_{0}, \dots, z_{n}$ are different numbers. Then, using ordinary least squares (OLS), i.e. we can get the solution $(\hat{c}_{1}, \hat{\phi}_{2})$ (which is, actually, the estimate) of the system.

Next, let us consider the following system
\begin{cases}
z_{2} - z_{1} = \phi(z_{1} - z_{0})\\
(z_{3} - z_{2})= \phi (z_{2} - z_{1})\\
\dots\\
(z_{n} - z_{n-1})=\phi (z_{n-1} - z_{n-2})
\end{cases}
and using OLS again let us get the solution for $\hat{\phi}_{2}$.

Why the solution in the second case is very different compare to the first one?

From what I can see from the simulations below, one can not just subtract rows in the system, which is correct for consistent system.

The python code for simulations is below.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import statsmodels.api as sm

"""
function for simulation of z_{t} (the previous value plus some noise)
"""
def simulate_z(nSample, phi, sigma_e, fVal, c):
    noise_e = sp.random.normal(0, sigma_e, nSample)
    z = np.zeros(nSample)
    z[0] = fVal
    for period in range(1, nSample):
        z[period] = c + phi * z[(period - 1)] + noise_e[period]
    return z

"""
OLS estimation
"""
def est_c_ph(z):
    x = z[0:-1]
    y = z[1:]
    p = sp.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    # Estimate phi
    phi_est = p[0]
    # Estimate c
    c_est = sp.mean(z) * (1 - phi_est)
    return [c_est, phi_est]

"""
values of the parameters for simulation
"""
phi = 0.95  # slope
c = 0.5  # intercept
sigma_e = 0.08  # standard deviation of observation noise
nSample = 500  # sample size
E = c / (1 - phi)  # mean value
fVal = E  # first value of the simulated process
"""
simulation of AR(1)
"""
z = simulate_z(nSample, phi, sigma_e, fVal, c)

c_est, phi_est = est_c_ph(z)
print("OLS [c, phi]: ", [c_est, phi_est])

"""
differencing of data
"""
z_dif = z[1:] - z[0:-1]

c_d_est, phi_d_est = est_c_ph(z_dif)
print("diff z OLS [c, phi]: ", [c_d_est, phi_d_est])
```

Comment: Your second system is not equivalent to the first. To make it equivalent, you have to add one more constraint $$z_1 = c + \phi z_0$$ By dropping this constraint, you allow a wider range of possible solutions, so it is not surprising that the best fit without it is different from the best fit with it.

Comment: Dear @Paul Sinclair, what if system is consistent (n=2)? In this case we would be able to make this transformation and $z_{2} - z_{1} = \phi(z_{1} - z_{0})$ would give us correct solution for $\theta$.

Comment: Dear @Paul Sinclair, system itself is not equivalent, we do not have $c$ in the second one. But why the solution for $\phi$ is very different?

Comment: Read the part of my previous comment that comes after the formula.